# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+n^3x^4}$ converges uniformly for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+n^3x^4}$$ converges uniformly for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My try:** for $x=0$, of course it converges. for $x\neq 0$ , then $\frac{x^2}{1+n^3x^4}\le \frac{1}{n^3x^2}$ hence converges.

I am uncertain for my try. Please verify it.

Comment: You show convergence, but not _uniform_ convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using standard real-analysis methods, you can prove that the maximum of $\frac{x^2}{1+n^3x^4}$ is attained when $x=\pm n^{-\frac34}$. That maximum is $\frac12n^{-\frac32}$. Therefore, by the Weierstrass $M$-test and since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac12n^{-\frac32}$ converges, the convergence is uniform in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! how can I forget this. I trapped to think about $x=0$